# android studio compile error when renderscriptSupportModeEnabled set to true

Tags: android, android-studio

When I set `renderscriptSupportModeEnabled` to `true`

```
{
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {

        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
```

my

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
```

will show this error:

> all com.android.support.libraries must use the exact same version

[image]

Comment: Did you try to change `25.3.0` to `25.0.2`?

Comment: @cricket_007 it shows here Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.0.2

Comment: Then you need to open the  sdk manager and update the tools

Comment: @cricket_007 i did update tools, but still unable to remove the error, in order to remove the error I have to set renderscriptSupportModeEnabled false

Comment: @cricket_007 apparently I have to set it to false, but I don't know why I still could make blur effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> com.android.support.libraries must use the exact same version

According to your warning call **25.0.2** instead of **25.3.0**

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.2'
```

Comment: it shows here Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:25.0.2